# Can the hadoop programm which write under the hadoop-2.2.0 run in hadoop-1.2.1?

Tags: hadoop, version

I have hadoop-2.2.0 in my PC and i have wrote a programme under this version. And now i need to test it in a big cluster, but in the hadoop in the cluster machine is hadoop-1.2.1.
When I try to run my programm on it, there is an error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ProgramDriver.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)

I googled and it seems the problem of the version. So Is it not possible to run the programm wrote in new version of hadoop on old version hadoop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: Always develop using the same version of Hadoop as your target cluster.  It will save you a huge amount of pain.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Next time maybe I should talk to the cluster manager first and then make the same environment. Thank you for your tipp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your  Map Reduce program and what classes it uses(My gut feeling is that is does not work). Hadoop-1.x.x to 2.x.x is major release change, so there will be major changes in the classes and the libraries that you use in your program. Having said that I encourage you to check the release notes for the version.

Comment: :( this means solange the package be used my programm is available in hadoop-1.2.1, then it will run ok in this old version?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to accomplish in your code. Most likely the package that you use might depend on other packages which might also have changed with the version. But you can give it a try.